# Inkscape shows wrong colors when zooming out

Tags: color, inkscape, zoom

I have an object in my image that consists of a lot of small dots (~10,000) clustered together in a very close space. Naturally many of the dots overlap. The problem I'm having is in setting the color of each dot. When I do so while zoomed in on the image, everything looks as I expect it to (note in the below image there are ~10,000 individual dots, or "rings", making up the larger circle. These small individual dots are what I'm talking about):

[image: zoomed in]

However, when I zoom out, the color of all the dots gets darker than the shade I assigned them:

[image: zoomed out]

When I look at the stroke paint for each of the dots inkscape still says they're the original color, but of course they no longer look that way. Does anyone know what might be causing this or how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Is your graphics card driver is up to date? Sorry can't really think of anything else that could be causing it because I can't actually replicate the problem myself. Also note that tech support questions are generally of topic here.